# ListView doesn't react on clicks

Tags: java, android

i am a beginer android-developer and i need some help:
There is a Fragment in my Project - TasksFragment, there is a ListView element on it. On ListView, using ArrayAdapter Items are formed by a custom layout for Item and then added to ListView. The problem is, that ListView don't react on click processing events.

Here are the code fragments:

TaskAdapter class...

```
  public class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, null);
        }

        Task task = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(task.getTitle());
        CheckBox solvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
        solvedCheckBox.setChecked(task.isSolved());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

ItemClick fragment.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_fragment, null);
    mTasks = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTasks();
    final ListView lvMain = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);
    lvMain.setClickable(true);
    TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Task task = (Task)lvMain.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), task.getTitle() + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddTaskActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

XML Layout for List_Item_Task

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/task_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Xml layout for tasks_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3f638b">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTasksFragmentHeader"
        android:text="Задачи"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewTasks" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your xml layout. of listview and items

Comment: Please show all layout with parent's linear and/or Relaytive layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your listview is not clickable.

Just add this in your checkbox layout

```
        android:focusable="false"
```

Your items xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/task_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"   //Add this
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_list_item_titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_list_item_solvedCheckBox"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Now it should work. I have tested it :)

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks a lot!
Couldn't resolve it for several days.

Comment: Glade to here this it helped :) happy coding